# Issue to sort array in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting, firefox

I got an issue while sorting arrays in webkit browsers. In firefox the sorting works very well but in chrome or safari it sorts only my last if() statement. For example in this code it sorts only this block: 
(The if conditions are tested and working)

```
if(printCategory == printCategoryTour)
    {
        function compare (a, b) {

        return b.tour_naechtigungen - a.tour_naechtigungen

    };
        chartDataRegions.sort(compare);
        pushValues();
    }
```

on this function:

```
function chartDataSortArray() 

{       

    arraySorted = [];

    if(printCategory == printCategoryBev)
    {
        function compare (a, b) {

        return b.bev - a.bev;

        };
        chartDataRegions.sort(compare);

        pushValues();
    }
    if(printCategory == printCategoryWirt)
    {
        function compare (a, b) {

        return b.wirt_unt_anzahl - a.wirt_unt_anzahl

        };
        chartDataRegions.sort(compare);
        pushValues();           
    }
    if(printCategory == printCategoryMob)
    {
        function compare (a, b) {

        return b.mob_einpendler - a.mob_einpendler 

        };
        chartDataRegions.sort(compare);
        pushValues();
    }
    if(printCategory == printCategoryTour)
    {
        function compare (a, b) {

        return b.tour_naechtigungen - a.tour_naechtigungen

        };
        chartDataRegions.sort(compare);
        pushValues();
    }   

function pushValues()
{   
    for(i = 0; i<chartDataRegions.length; i++)
{
    arraySorted.push(chartDataRegions[i])

}
}
```

Hmm i tried it now 2 hours but i dont get it to work !
Does anybody find the issue ?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to show the problem?

Comment: here you get the url of the page..
If you click on the nav button the chart in the bottom shold show the values sorted! And this work only on the last button [link](http://weedmap.de)

Comment: WeedMap.de! right ok

Comment: you will see it only works well in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the compare function once !
It looks better and works crossbrowser

```
function chartDataSortArray() 

{       

        arraySorted = [];

            function compare (a, b) {
                if(printCategory == printCategoryBev)
                    {
                        return b.bev - a.bev;
                    }
                if(printCategory == printCategoryWirt)
                    {
                        return b.wirt_unt_anzahl - a.wirt_unt_anzahl;
                    }
                if(printCategory == printCategoryMob)
                    {
                        return b.mob_einpendler - a.mob_einpendler
                    }
                if(printCategory == printCategoryTour)
                    {
                        return b.tour_naechtigungen - a.tour_naechtigungen
                    }
                };
            function pushValues()
            {   
                for(i = 0; i<chartDataRegions.length; i++)
                    {
                        arraySorted.push(chartDataRegions[i])
                    }
            }


    chartDataRegions.sort(compare);

    pushValues();

}
```